# How to generate coverage report from ctest in python?

Tags: python, code-coverage, ctest

I have a python script "sample.py" which is executing few ctest. I want to have a coverage report generated once ctest are executed. The coverage report should be named as "test.cov". I looked around and found "pytest-cov" could be helpful but nowhere I am getting how to make use of it. Does pytest-cov has to be added in the import statement or not. It's not clear.

Please help me understand how can I generate coverage of the ctest in python.

Comment: What are "ctest"?

Comment: Could you please add a sample code of what you're doing. It's not very clear what is your problem.

Comment: i'm confused.. Are you trying to cover C, C++, python, or other code?